# Rapid connection and disconnection of external monitor from M2 Pro Mac

Tags: macos, display, usb

I have an M2 Pro MacBook Pro running Sonoma 14.3

Previously, I could connect my MacBook to my external monitor, an HP Z32 (4k 60Hz) using a USB-C cable and have the display work. However, after updating the Mac to [macOS Sonoma 14.3](https://eclecticlight.co/2024/01/22/apple-has-released-macos-sonoma-14-3-and-security-updates-for-ventura-and-monterey/), the display will come on for maybe half a second and drop out.

I can connect over HDMI, but then I can't use the USB hub built into my monitor.

On my previous Intel mac, I used a [EDID override](https://github.com/mbruggmann/osx-edid-overrides) script to correct for a similar problem, but looks like that isn't supported on the new ARM chips.

Potentially relevant is this [discussion](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/674047) which references an app called BetterDisplay.

Answer (score 1):

I took a few debugging steps:

- Installed (And uninstalled) BetterView
- Reconnected the monitor without my keyboard attached to the USB on the monitor
- Connected the monitor over HDMI and changed the color-profile to sRGB (and set the monitor into sRGB mode using the onscreen display).
- Installed Wacom drivers for my touch-pad (this seems un-related, but my monitor connected up correctly after this. Thought I'd mention)

I also made sure that when it was on internal+external display mode, the computer would set the resolution to "Default" 3008x1692 mode + "Internal" to "Default" 1512x982 mode. I hypothesised that maybe the display firmware for the M2 chip has a bug supporting max resolution on both displays. In external-only mode, its set to 4k. I did have to use the HDMI to set these settings since the display was disconnecting so much.

It seems like this seems to have resolved the issue (touch-wood)

[image]